# Dictionary Key Accessing by numeric index

Tags: c#

I need to access last-inserted Key inside the Dictionary, I do not know the name of it.

```
int LastCount = mydict[mydict.keys[mydict.keys.Count]];
```

It does not work because `Dictionary.Keys` does not implement indexer.

if there is any way, essentially a Dictionary that implements an []-indexer on the Keys?

Comment: An `OrderedDictionary` should do the trick. But afaik there's no generic version out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no such thing as a "last inserted key".

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=net-6.0) specifically says:

> The order of the keys in the Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection is unspecified

You will have to modify the piece of code that inserts into the dictionary and keep track of the last inserted value there.